# Android emulator not connect to socket.io on localhost

Tags: android, sockets, socket.io

My js code:

```
const   express = require('express'),
        http = require('http'),
        app = express(),
        server = http.createServer(app),
        io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Chat Server is running on port 3000');
});

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log('user connected');
});

server.listen(3000, ()=>{
    console.log('Node app is running on port 3000')
});
```

If I open `http://127.0.0.1:3000` in browser, I receive message

But in android I can not connect to socket

My android code :

```
try {
            Socket socket = IO.socket("http://127.0.0.1:3000");
            socket.connect();
            Log.i("errorCheck", "ID: "+socket.id());
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I tested other ip like : 10.0.2.2, 10.0.2.3, localhost, modem config ip, my real ip

And 4444, 8080 port

But not work

I use genymotion emulator

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The android emulator also has it's own localhost because it behaves as a separate entity.It will therefore not be able to access localhost directly from the host (your computer). If you want to access localhost from your computer, use 10.0.2.2 which is a special alias to your host loopback interface.

[Set up Android Emulator networking](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-networking.html)