# How to receive a message with socket from client using a thread on different class java android studio

Tags: java, android, multithreading, sockets, server

So, here I'm trying to receive a String from a client using TCP Socket. I made a class which recalls an external class with a thread. I think that the part that receives the message is ok but I don't know why the ServerSocket refuses external connection. I have already put the request for internet permission in the manifest file in fact I have one more Async Task class that sends messages with socket and it works just fine. So the problem is in the Thread I think because it doesn't let my client to connect to the ServerSocket.

Here is the code of the class that receives the message

```
import android.os.Handler;

import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;


public class Message_reciver implements Runnable {


Socket s;
ServerSocket ss;
DataInputStream data;
String message = "";
Handler handler = new Handler();

@Override
public void run() {

    try {
        ss = new ServerSocket(5050);

        while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {

            System.out.println("Waiting for client");
            s = ss.accept();
            System.out.println("Connected");
            data = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
            message = data.readUTF();

            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    System.out.println(message);
                }
            });

        }



    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

}

And here is the class that executes the Thread:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new Message_reciver());
thread.start();
```

Obviously those two lines of code are in the OnCreate method. In the console it is printed "Waiting for client" but not "Connected" so I don't know why it refuses connections.

This is the code of the client (but it isn't the problem):

```
   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  
  Socket socket = new Socket("192.168.1.176", 5050);
  PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
  writer.print("HI");
  writer.close();
  socket.close();
```

}

}

So if anyone knows the solution, please help I'm stuck in this problem since 5 hours thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that the IP is correct? I've just copied the code, ran the Server, then the client and I see "Connected" in the console.

Comment: @jwpol Yeah the IP is correct because otherwise I would get connection timed out but I get connection refused. Did you run the thread in a emulator in android studio?

Comment: No, just Intellij.

Comment: @jwpol Ok if I run it in visual studio it works fine but in android studio everything changed and I don't know why. If you have it installed could you please try to run it in android studio with an emulator? Thanks :)

Comment: Check out this thread, potentially this is the issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57436151/android-emulator-not-connect-to-socket-io-on-localhost

Comment: I'm glad I could help :)